# During Implementation of Multiprocessing the function run more number of times

Tags: python

I'm learning multiprocessing for my project, so before directly implement this in my project I practiced it. and code is something like that

```
# imports
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import as_completed

def printf(flag):
    print("this function takes flag and acts accordingly")

    if flag == 0:
        print(f"flag value - {flag}")
    elif flag == 1:
        print(f"flag value - {flag}")
    elif flag == 2:
        print(f"flag value - {flag}")
    elif flag == 3:
        print(f"flag value - {flag}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [executor.submit(printf, flags) for flags in range(0, 4)]

        for f in as_completed(results):
            printf(f.result())
```

according to me, the function must run only 4 times because the range is given is [0,4] but when I execute it gives 8 output instead of 4

**expected output:**

```
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 0
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 1
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 2
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 3
```

**Output Come:**

```
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 0
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 1
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 2
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 3
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
```

does it mean the function runs 8 times instead of just 4 why has it happened?

thanks in advance

**Edit:** after replacing printf with print in for loop (just silly mistake which I can't see) when I run this it's print the none values in the output

```
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 0
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 1
None
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 2
this function takes flag and acts accordingly
flag value - 3
None
None
None
```

why?

Comment: The None are because you are printing the return value, but your function doesn’t explicitly return a value so None is returned.

Comment: I get it , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `printf` again at the end:

```
for f in as_completed(results):
    printf(f.result())
```

The bottom four output lines you get are probably because of this.

Comment: Probably meant to write print(f.result())

Comment: Thank you, I can't see this it's just a silly mistake I write printf instead of print